# rails - how do I create an application with rails new, specifing rspec for testing and haml for views at that moment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, haml

Rails 3.1

I can do:
`rails new myApp -d mysql` to set the database ok.

Is it possible to set rspec at the same time (or is it the default in 3.1?) and haml.

I googled and looked in the guides but it was not clear.

I know I can add rspec and haml gems and go from there but I was wondering if there are options to set those when doing `rails new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I think it's because Rails has dependencies on mysql and other databases, whereas it has no support for rspec or any testing tool other than test/unit / minitest.

Comment: Thanks David, that's what I had found. I will upvote and accept.